# seaborn change clustermap visualization options without redoing the clustering

Tags: python, seaborn, hierarchical-clustering

Is it possible to run seaborn.clustermap on a previously obtained `ClusterGrid` object?

For example I user clustermap to obtain g in the following example:

```
import seaborn as ns
data = sns.load_dataset("iris")
species = iris.pop("species")

g = sns.clustermap(
    data, 
    cmap="mako",
    col_cluster=False,
    yticklabels=False, figsize=(5, 10),
    method='ward',
    metric="euclidean"
)
```

I would like to try different visualization options like different colormaps, figure sizes, how it looks with and without labels etc.

With the `iris` dataset everything is really fast, but I have a way larger dataset and the clustering part takes a lot of time.

Can I use `g` to show the heatmap and dendrogram using different options?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the object returned by `clustermap` is of type `ClusterGrid`. That object is not really documented in `seaborn`, however, it is essentially just a container for a few `Axes` objects. Depending on the kind of manipulations you want to make, you may simply need to access the relevant `Axes` object or the figure itself:

```
# change the figure size after the fact
g.fig.set_size_inches((4,4))
# remove the labels of the heatmap
g.ax_heatmap.set_xticklabels([])
```

The colormap thing is a little more difficult to access. `clustermap` uses matplotlib `pcolormesh` under the hood. This function returns a `collection` object (`QuadMesh`), which is store in the list of collections of the main axes (`g.ax_heatmap.collections`). Since, AFAIK, seaborn doesn't plot anything else on that axes, We can get the `QuadMesh` object by its index `[0]`, and then we can use any function applicable to that object.

```
# change the colormap used
g.ax_heatmap.collections[0].set_cmap('seismic')
```

Comment: To define your own colormap, e.g. a diverging colormap for correlated features, you can use ```from matplotlib.colors import ListedColormap; wanted_cmap = ListedColormap(sns.diverging_palette(240, 10, n=9)); g.ax_heatmap.collections[0].set_cmap(wanted_cmap)```